# View different parts of a file, in different terminals, scrolled in synchrony?

Tags: terminal, vim, android, tmux

Two terminals, on different machines, viewing consecutive parts of a file in vim. You scroll/move cursor in one terminal, and the other moves the same relative amount. So you get one logical window covering two physical displays.

- In `vim`, `:scrollbind` does this, but between vim-windows - not across terminals/machines.
- In `tmux`, you can connect to the same session from another terminal/machine, but you see the same thing on each terminal - not consecutive parts of a file.

Maybe... (somehow) make the `tmux` window much bigger than the physical display, so you only see the top half of it,,, and on the other machine/terminal (somehow) view that same window at an offset, so you only see the bottom half of it?

Nice to have this work for the whole terminal, but all I really need is for it work for vim.

*Usage*: double-headed smartphone: double display size by using *two* smartphones... (using termux.com)

**EDIT** other ways to use two phones more simply:

- output on the other phone
- docs on the other
- edit different files on the two phones (or, the same file, with the other phone Read only). Control the second phone from the keyboard on the first phone, by having it in its own `tmux` session and connecting to it from the other phone (as above). On the first phone,  switch tabs to edit it or change the position of the file, then switch back to the main tab. So second display acts as a kind of docs.

Comment: Did you consider just not using smartphones for this but instead a device with a bigger display to begin with?

Comment: @Seth I did. (i) To save money I'd like o use devices I already have (ii) double-headed phones would be awesome/cute. But you made me think of another solution: buy a big cheap tablet (old, slow and out of date), and `ssh` into my phone from it.